# How do I split a column to many colum by row quantity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a long single column DataFrame as following table:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 |
| Cell 4 |
| Cell 5 |
| Cell 6 |
| Cell 7 |
| Cell 8 |

I want to split column A in order with specify row quantity and add to others new columns
If I give 2 row quantity for each column

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 3 | Cell 5 | Cell 7 |
| Cell 2 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 | Cell 8 |

split long a single column to new adding column by given row quantity.

Comment: Show a [mcve] of what you have tried so far. Read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include more details. Maybe take a look at what a [mre] is. Also looking at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391) would also help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the underlying numpy array to [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) in **F**ortran order (rows, then columns):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

N = 2

out = (pd.DataFrame(df['Column A'].to_numpy().reshape(N, -1, order='F'))
        # the line below is optional, just to have the column names
         .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase))).add_prefix('Column ')
      )
```

Output:

```
  Column A Column B Column C Column D
0   Cell 1   Cell 3   Cell 5   Cell 7
1   Cell 2   Cell 4   Cell 6   Cell 8
```

If you want to handle `N` that are non multiples of `len(df)`, you can add a [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) step to pad the DataFrame with NaNs:

```
N = 3

out = (pd.DataFrame(df['Column A'].reindex(range(int(np.ceil(len(df)/N)*N)))
                                  .to_numpy().reshape(N, -1, order='F'))
         .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase))).add_prefix('Column ')
      )
```

Output:

```
  Column A Column B Column C
0   Cell 1   Cell 4   Cell 7
1   Cell 2   Cell 5   Cell 8
2   Cell 3   Cell 6      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could divide the rows into groups and pivot the groups into columns.

**Short Version**

```
number_rows = 2
df['cols'] = np.ceil(df['Column A'].expanding().count()/number_rows)
df.index = pd.Series(range(len(df))) % number_rows
df = df.pivot(columns='cols', values='Column A')
```

```
cols     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0
0     Cell 0  Cell 2  Cell 4  Cell 6
1     Cell 1  Cell 3  Cell 5  Cell 7
```

The code will also work if your number of rows to split by (`number_rows`) are not a multiple of length of your DataFrame, and missing values (`np.nan`) will be added.

**Long Version with Explanation of Steps**

Create demo data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': [f'Cell {i}' for i in range(4)]})
```

```
  Column A
0   Cell 0
1   Cell 1
2   Cell 2
3   Cell 3
```

Create columns for later columns and rows

```
number_rows = 3 # 3 instead of 2 to illustrate filling with missing values
df['cols'] = np.ceil(df['Column A'].expanding().count()/number_rows)
df['cols'] = 'Column '+df['cols'].astype(int).astype(str)
df['rows'] = pd.Series(range(len(df))) % number_rows
```

```
  Column A      cols  rows
0   Cell 0  Column 1     0
1   Cell 1  Column 1     1
2   Cell 2  Column 1     2
3   Cell 3  Column 2     0
```

Pivot table

```
df = df.pivot(columns='cols', index='rows', values='Column A')
```

```
cols Column 1 Column 2
rows                  
0      Cell 0   Cell 3
1      Cell 1      NaN
2      Cell 2      NaN
```

You can remove the column and index names with:

```
df.columns.name = df.index.name = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You should Create a new row, with the name of new columns corresponding to each value and also change the correpoding index. Finally you can use `df.pivot()`
to pivot your dataframe to the new format.

```
n_rows = 2
df['new_col'] = "Column "
df['new_col']=df['new_col']+pd.Series(df.index%n_rows).ne(1).cumsum().astype(str)
df.index=df.index%n_rows
print(df.pivot(columns='new_col', values='Column A'))

new_col Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4
0         Cell 1   Cell 3   Cell 5   Cell 7
1         Cell 2   Cell 4   Cell 6   Cell 8
```